# How to launch a dmg one by one in MAC OSX using Shell?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sh

I am using MAC OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion.

I am preparing a Shell Script to launch 3 dmg files one by one.

I want to launch the dmg file each one after the another dmg has been installed.

I am using the wait function in script, but it is waiting till one dmg has been closed.

Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: can you clarify what you're asking? What are you doing with the dmgs? Are you just copying contents to `/Applications` or are you executing something in each? dmg is a "volume" file, so saying `dmg has been installed` makes no sense. You don't install a dmg, you either copy the content or run an installation app within.

Comment: I have 3 dmg file, i want to launch first one, in first one i will copy contents to /Applications, after closing first dmg, second dmg should launch automatically, this is my requirement.

Comment: Why not launch all 3 toeing and then drag ?

Answer (score 8):

here's a way you can open dmg files, copy the app and unmount the volume, for each volume:

```
for f in *.dmg: do
    VOLUME=$(hdiutil attach "$f" | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')
    cp -r "$VOLUME/"*.app /Applications/
    diskutil unmount "$VOLUME"
done
```

to be ran in the directory of the dmg files.

Comment: not block means what? I cant get you?

Comment: hum… I'm not sure I do understand your question

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, however the `awk` expression does not work correctly in case the volume name contains spaces. Here's my modified version: `awk '{$1=$2=""; gsub(/^ +/,"",$0); print $0}'`

Comment: oh my… awk is such a pain that I'm not sure I can actually take it and edit my answer only by reading what you wrote :-s

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Mac OS X [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command. It automatically will open a file with the registered Mac program based upon its suffix.

```
$ open foo.dmg   # Opens and mounts the disk image in Finder.
```

It returns back to the current process in Terminal, so your shell script can continue (although the active app on your Mac will be Finder). You can use `umount /Volumes/<image name>` to unmount the disk image. A **Word 'o Warning**: The name of the *Volume* may be different than the name of the DMG file.